# Anonymous function not containing any parameter name?

Tags: c#, azure

Below is method declaration has been used in one of our interfaces to read entity from Azure table storage.
`QueryEntity` method is not having any variable associated with `Func<IQueryable<TElement>` parameter.

How does it work?

```
    bool QueryEntity(string tableName, string partitionKey, out List<TElement> retrievedEntity,
    out string errorMessage,Expression<Func<TElement, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TElement>, 
    IOrderedQueryable<TElement>> orderBy = null);
```

Comment: @Rune I have rolled back your edit. You've just fixed the question to the point where its fixed and makes sense. I have rolled back so that people viewing this can see where the confusion is.

Comment: Thanks, I realized after the edit that I had accidentally answered the question as well :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the type given to the `orderBy` argument. It is split across two lines.. hence your confusion. Put it on one line and it becomes:

```
Func<IQueryable<TElement>, IOrderedQueryable<TElement>> orderBy = null
```

A `Func<T1, T2>` delegate. It also has a default value of `null`.. so if you don't supply it when calling the function.. it is inferred to be `null`.